# Как добавить иконку рабочего стола / сеть в Ненативном QFileDialog?

Tags: qt

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Слева нету перехода на рабочий стол. Можно ли каким то флагом ее добавить?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#setSidebarUrls

Comment: А какой путь до вкладки сеть?